# Server migration different PHP settings

Tags: php, migration, php-5.3, plesk

I'm migrating a long list of websites from an old server using RedHat6 to a new server on CentOS7. Both are Plesk. But the websites on old server are using 5.3.3 by OS vendor Apache module which is not available on the new server. The closes I got for PHP 5.3 on new server are:

- 5.3.29 CGI application
- 5.3.29 FastCGI application

I'm using the Plesk migrator tool, so I really don't want to click the continue button if it's going to mess up. Any suggestions or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated:

> But the websites on old server are using 5.3.3 by OS vendor **Apache module** which is not available on the new server

Please note, that you are able to list your PHP - handlers on servers where Plesk is installed with the command *( logged in as user "root" over SSH )*:

```
plesk bin php_handler --list
```

For security reasons, Plesk disabled the "Apache module" ( id = module ) as a standart configuration. If you still would like to be able to use this insecure and outdated PHP - handler, you are able to ENABLE it ( **IF** it had been installed on your server by you, for your serverwide PHP version! ) with the example command:

```
plesk bin php_handler --enable -id module
```

Plesk PHP - versions don't include the insecure, outdated Apache - module as a PHP - handler, so you won't find with the list - command. Only CGI and FastCGI are available for the Plesk PHP version 5.3 . Plesk PHP - versions higher than 5.3 include as well the corresponding FPM - PHP - Handler.